# sim-based mobile phone tracking

Tags: geolocation, gps

I'm not sure, if it's the right place here to ask this question.

But can anybody explain more detaild, how sim-based mobile phone tracking's working, und **if it costs anything** (the second part is very important)?

Comment: How did you get a rep of 633 and still not know what type of questions can be asked on StackOverflow? :) If you ware writing an app to perform tracking then maybe, otherwise I don't think SO is the best place for this question.

Comment: The problem is, it is an important question for my app. And i was ready to get minus-points for that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_tracking) explains it pretty well:

> Mobile phone tracking tracks the current position of a mobile phone even on the move. To locate the phone, it must emit at least the roaming signal to contact the next nearby antenna tower, but the process does not require an active call. GSM localisation is then done by multilateration based on the signal strength to nearby antenna masts.

So as soon as your phone is turned on, it starts to emit signals that the antennas catch. If several of them receive the signal, that (and the signal strength) gives a pretty good indication of your location.

It needs a bit of software (which the law requires today), so it doesn't cost anything "extra" for the people that provide the hardware. It's not free for normal people to use, though.

Comment: I said the same, but i didn't find any evidence for my words. The colleagues of mine meant, that probably some data packets should be sent to estimate location and that would cost some money. But they had also no evidence.

Comment: The "data" packets are sent but they don't cost money; they are simple "I'm here, who else?" screams of your mobile phone which the network uses to connect you with your provider. Without those, no one would be able to call you on the street because the network would have no idea where you are.

Comment: these were my words as well :)

Answer (score 1):

sim based? mobile phone tracking goes in layers, just like PC. At first GPS, if phone don't have it then it counts what mobile providers towers covers the phone and how strong mobile signal is from each tower, so by that it can counts you location. It Don't cost for telephone companies but it might for you since it depends on connection provided by towers. So its not the thing you can do without providers knowing it.